# R/GIS: Transform GPS tracks to line segments, and retain the start_time and end_time

Tags: r, gis, arcgis

I have a long GPS track representing a route of boat survey, which looks like:

> ```
> Id  X       Y        time                           
> 1   274604  2778803  2016/5/5 08:31:34  
> 2   274589  2778804  2016/5/5 08:31:49  
> 3   274564  2778811  2016/5/5 08:32:04  
> 4   274538  2778818  2016/5/5 08:32:19  
> 5   274511  2778822  2016/5/5 08:32:34  
> ...
> ```

For analysis, I transformed this point layer into polyline, and then split the line into 100 equal segments (conducted in ArcMap). How can I get the information of start time and end time of each segment? Something like:

> ```
> SegmentId  time_start         time_end  
> 1          2016/5/5 08:31:34  2016/5/5 08:50:00  
> 2          2016/5/5 08:50:00  2016/5/5 09:12:25  
> 3          2016/5/5 09:12:25  2016/5/5 09:35:12  
> ...
> ```

I approached it by identifying the split points, finding their nearest neighbor within the layer of track points to extract the time. But it's erroneous, because the route has some overlapped parts (same coordinates but different time).

Any help would be highly appreciated!